# How do I resolve reportMissingImports problem when importing flask?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So, I'm a complete newbie and all of the technical jargon I was finding searching for how to solve this program gave me a headache.

I'm trying to install flask on vsCode. I just downloaded vsCode and Python on my mac a few days ago. Now I'm trying to install flask. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojzNmvkNfqc exactly ,but when it came to the step to test out flask, I got this error "import flask could not be resolvedpylance reportmissingimports". Some differences I noticed in the process were that the "We noticed a new virtual workspace ..." message did not pop up, "pylint is not installed" did not pop up, and the .vscode folder with setting.json did not pop up. However, when I entered the command to install flask in the terminal it said installed successfully.

The two intro to C++ courses I've taken have not prepared me for understanding related sources of people having this problem. If anyone can explain to me how I might go about trouble shooting this in jargon-less terms as if I were a middle school kid I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you executed `python3 -m venv venv` at `4:58`? It's used to create a new virtual environment. Then he executed `source venv/bin/activate` to activate the virtual environment. After that, he executed `pip install flask`. This means he installed the flask module into the `venv` virtual environment.

You can click the python interpreter on the bottom-left of the VSCode to switch the python environment. And after you switch the environment remember create a new terminal through shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+`**, then the terminal will activate the python interpreter you have selected, then you can install the modules into the right place.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure why but opening workspace JSON and pasting the path to my python3 allowed me to install flask without this problem